# Animate text transform uppercase

Tags: html, css, text

I'd like to have a transition to text-transform:uppercase when I mouse-over a link.  I've tried:

```
a{
    font-size:20px;
animation-duration: 0.4s;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover{
text-transform:uppercase;   
}
```

But that had no effect, it just pops to uppercase.  Any ideas?

Comment: What would the animation look like? You will need some SVG library or something similar to do this: http://raphaeljs.com/helvetica.html

Comment: If @Blender's link is the kind of animation you're expecting, there's no way to do that with CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that there's no way to do a gradual transition on a style that has no intermediate values. For instance, you could change the width from 100px to 200px, because there are 99 intermediate values between the two. But what are the intermediate values between lowercase and uppercase (values you can set an element to at any time, like 150px or 170px in the width example)?

Maybe you could fake the transition a little by fading the text out (or halfway out), changing it to uppercase, and then fading the text back in (might require jQuery).

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're right about the intermediate values.  I also tried faking it with a 4px font size increase, but it just isn't ideal.  Ah well, back to a text-shadow.

Comment: Here's an [**idea**](http://motyar.blogspot.com/2010/09/text-morphing-effect-with-css.html)

Comment: @arttronics: I guess that would mean using text-shadow to blur the lowercase text out, change it to uppercase, and then blur it back in. That's a better idea, though ie9 doesn't support text-shadow.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a transition for text-transform.